# OnItemClickListener doesn't fire

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

**The Register Button works well, but the debugger doesn't run into the setOnItemClickListener onItemClick. If You click on a item, the activity for editing the record should be launched.**

```
package at.bomsbg.MindX;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import at.bomsbg.MindX.sqlite.helper.MindXopenHelper;
import at.bomsbg.MindX.sqlite.helper.MindXtableAdapter;

public class Activity_cardmanager extends Activity {
MindXtableAdapter mindxtableadapt;
MindXopenHelper openHelper;

ListView nameList;
Button registerBtn;
Cursor cursor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardmanager);
    nameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    mindxtableadapt = new MindXtableAdapter(this);

    String[] from = { MindXopenHelper.title, MindXopenHelper.detail,
            MindXopenHelper.active };
    int[] to = { R.id.tv_title, R.id.tv_detail, R.id.tv_active };

    cursor = mindxtableadapt.queryName();
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = 
                 new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
    nameList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> tobjParent, View tobjView,
                int tintPosition, long tlngid) {
            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) tobjParent
                    .getItemAtPosition(tintPosition);
            int nameId = listCursor.getInt(listCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MindXopenHelper.KEY_ID));
            passdata.putInt(MindXopenHelper.KEY_ID, nameId);
            Intent passIntent = new Intent(Activity_cardmanager.this,
                    Activity_edit_mindxtables.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    Integer.toString(nameId), 500).show();

            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });

    registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Activity_cardmanager.this,
                    Activity_MindXtablesRecord.class);
            startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cursor.requery();

}
```

}

activity_Cardmanager.html

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml
**I add the item clickable for the textfield. I think that is not realy necesarry.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_detail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:width="100dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/tv_active"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe another onItemClickListener is set, overriding yours. Try setting the listener after the register button is clicked. So if then you click the button and afterwards click an item and it now works - I am right. If I am - you should set the listener in another point of time, where the overriding listener is already set.

Comment: the checkbox is eating up your listeners.

Comment: **thank You,
I tried the first Option that You suggested, afterward I did:**

 public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  setViewIttemListener();  
 }

without success.
I believe, that I've a Problem in the Body of the OnItemClick()

Answer (score 0):

You have focusable/clickable items in your list view item - the checkbox.

Option 1 - Set the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` flag to your `ListView` and you should have fired the `onItemClickListener`.

Option 2 - In your Adapter you can set an `onClickListener` on the entire list view item object, and handle it from there.

Comment: **bold** thank You, 
the idea was good. Maybe it´s troubled it more. But I removed the checkbox and it happens the same.

Comment: Hi again asteidl, I just noticed that you have set "clickable=true" to one  TextView... and this does exactly the same as the checkbox. So, even if you remove the checkbox, you have another item that handles your click. Did you try the "descendantFocusability" flag? This is made exactly for this kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

the Problem of my solution was on row.xml

again thanX on all:

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:clickable="true" (removed)

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:onClick="Title" (added)
    android:clickable="true" (added)
    android:focusable="true" (added)
```

on my Activity_cardmanager I inserted following code after nameList.setAdapter...

```
nameList.setClickable(true);            // 2015-04-14
nameList.setFocusable(true);            // 2015-04-14
nameList.setItemsCanFocus(true);        // 2015-04-14
setViewItemListener();
```

.
.
.

```
    public void setViewItemListener() {
        nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> tobjParent, View tobjView, int tintPosition, long tlngid) {
                Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
//              Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) tobjParent.getItemAtPosition(tintPosition);
                Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) nameList.getItemAtPosition(tintPosition);  //2015-04-15
                int nameId = listCursor.getInt(listCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MindXopenHelper.KEY_ID));
                passdata.putInt(MindXopenHelper.KEY_ID, nameId);
                Intent passIntent = new Intent(Activity_cardmanager.this,
                        Activity_edit_mindxtables.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 Integer.toString(nameId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }
        });     
    }
```

the returnValue is true, but that is another story.